# Dealing with OutOfMemoryError local resources

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory, drawable

How do I use large amounts of `ImageView` on the same screen?

**My activity screen:**

[image]

I have this type of layout, every image is separate `ImageView`.

On some devices it throws `OutOfMemoryError`, however there are these devices where it works perfectly.

One of the "solutions" I've found on stack:
copy all of the drawable folder content to drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and so on, for some time it wasn't giving any `OutOfMemoryError` errors. However, it increased the total size of my app by several MB.

I'm not sure about the bitmap processing approach.

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/mainbg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/livingwall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bglivingback"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/windowliving"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/windowliving"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline13" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bagetpower"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/livingbaget"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline13"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline18"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline17"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/curtainliving"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curtainliving"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline22"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wallclock"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/clockliving"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline12"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline16"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline15" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wallpicture"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpicture"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline12"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline11"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline13" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bookman"

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bookshelfliving"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline16"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline15" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/floorliving"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#596c64"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/carpetliving"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/carpetlivingroom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/floorliving"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/floorliving"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/floorliving"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/armchairliving"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/armchairliving"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/chestliving"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/chestliving"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.604"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tvliving"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tvliving"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline26"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline12"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sofaliving"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sofaliving"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/extradetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/carpetliving"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/livingwall"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/livingwall"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:background="#eee">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/soundplayer"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/soundicon"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/langrewwrtie"
            style="@style/rooms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="langrew" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/translation"
            style="@style/rooms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="Translation" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/howtoread"
            style="@style/rooms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="Howtoread" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closeit"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/closeicon"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.79" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.31" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.52" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.86" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4703125" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.96" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.52" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.14" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9867188" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2338377" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.64" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.29" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.484375" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.11" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline22"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3765625" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline23"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="801dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="509dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline26"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.70321363" />
```

Here is my java:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

/**
 * Created by ImRock on 2/19/2018.
 */

public class RoomLiving extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public RoomLiving(){}

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;


    String jsonString;
    String[] names;
    String current;
    TypedArray soundslist;
    private boolean hiddingdetails = true;
    int where;
    int hero;
    int taps=0;
    InputStream is;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    Context context;

    String woot;




    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    TextView hebrewwrite, translation, howtoread;
    ImageView livingwall, windowliving,curtainliving, wallclock, bookshelf, wallpicture, floorliving, carpetliving, armchairliving, chestliving, tvliving, sofaliving;
    Button soundplayerb, closeitb;
    LinearLayout extra;
    String[] learning;

    int[] sounds = new int [] {R.raw.wall, R.raw.window, R.raw.curtain, R.raw.clock, R.raw.bookshelf, R.raw.picture, R.raw.floor, R.raw.carpet, R.raw.armchair, R.raw.roomcabinet, R.raw.tv, R.raw.sofa};



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);



        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roomliving, container, false);

//View view2 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
//View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

//view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//view.setVisibility(View.GONE);//  View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        //view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;






        if (String.valueOf(current).equals("ru_UA") || String.valueOf(current).equals("uk_UA") || String.valueOf(current).equals("ru_MD") || String.valueOf(current).equals("ru_RU") || String.valueOf(current).equals("ru_BY")){
            InputStream isrus = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.feeder);
            Resources res = getResources();

                    jsonBuddy jb = new jsonBuddy(isrus);
                    jsonString = jb.getJsonString();
                    learning = res.getStringArray(R.array.room);

                    names = res.getStringArray(R.array.room);
                    soundslist = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.roomsounds);
                }




        else {
         InputStream iseng = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.feedereng);
    Resources res = getResources();

                    jsonBuddy jb = new jsonBuddy(iseng);
                    jsonString = jb.getJsonString();
                    learning = res.getStringArray(R.array.room);

                    names = res.getStringArray(R.array.itemsname);
                    soundslist = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.soundslist);




        }






        extra = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.extradetails);


        hebrewwrite = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.hebrewwrtie);
        translation = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.translation);
        howtoread = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.howtoread);

        livingwall = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.livingwall);
        windowliving = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.windowliving);
        curtainliving = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.curtainliving);
        wallclock = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.wallclock);
        bookshelf = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bookman);
        wallpicture = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.wallpicture);
        floorliving = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.floorliving);
        carpetliving = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.carpetliving);
        armchairliving = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.armchairliving);
        chestliving = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.chestliving);
        tvliving = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvliving);
        sofaliving = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sofaliving);
        soundplayerb = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.soundplayer);
        closeitb = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.closeit);



        livingwall.setOnClickListener(this);
        windowliving.setOnClickListener(this);
        curtainliving.setOnClickListener(this);
        wallclock.setOnClickListener(this);
        wallpicture.setOnClickListener(this);
        floorliving.setOnClickListener(this);
        carpetliving.setOnClickListener(this);
        armchairliving.setOnClickListener(this);
        chestliving.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvliving.setOnClickListener(this);
        sofaliving.setOnClickListener(this);
        soundplayerb.setOnClickListener(this);
        closeitb.setOnClickListener(this);
        bookshelf.setOnClickListener(this);




        return rootView;
    }

    public void extrainfo(final String curitem){
        if(!hiddingdetails){

            hiddingdetails = true;
            extra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(names);
            if (list.contains(curitem)){
                where =  list.indexOf(curitem);
            }
            extra.animate().setDuration(400);
            extra.animate().translationY(200);


            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    loadup(curitem);
                    showit();
                }
            }, 500);


        }
        else {
            extra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hiddingdetails = false;
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(names);

            if (list.contains(curitem)){
                where =  list.indexOf(curitem);
            }
            extra.animate().setDuration(400);
            extra.animate().translationY(0);


            loadup(curitem);
            showit();

            Log.e("wat", curitem + String.valueOf(where));


        }

    }

    public void hideit(){

        hiddingdetails = true;
        extra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        extra.animate().setDuration(400);
        extra.animate().translationY(200);
    }

    public void showit(){
        hiddingdetails = false;
        extra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        extra.animate().setDuration(400);
        extra.animate().translationY(0);

    }


    private void loadup(String wordfind) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("letters");
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject scan = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                String wordjson = scan.getString("word");
                String wordlikerussian = scan.getString("wordlikerussian");
                String wordinhe = scan.getString("wordinhe");
                String word = scan.getString("word");


                if (wordjson.equals(wordfind)){

                    hebrewwrite.setText(wordinhe);
                    translation.setText(current);
                    howtoread.setText(wordlikerussian);

                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void playingman (int l){
        tapcounter();


        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), sounds[l]);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });
        mMediaPlayer.start();






    }

    public void tapcounter(){

        taps++;

        if (taps==10){

            if(mInterstitial.isLoaded()){

                mInterstitial.show();
            }
            else {

                taps = 0;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: @jonathanrz updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Glide library to load images in image view.

> Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image
>   loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and 
>   disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use
>   interface

You can use Glide like below

```
Glide.with(fragment)
        .load(url)
        .into(imageView);
```